# Random unique Mysql Id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table and want to genarate random unique value to it using 1 mysql query.
Table structure like:

```
id | unique_id
1  | 1
2  | 5
3  | 2
4  | 7
```

etc

unique_id is integer(10) unsigned

So I want to fullfill unique_id field with unique random value (not 1, 5, 2, 7 in my example) every time.

Algorytm is:

```
1. Get 1 unique random value, which will not have duplicates in unique_id field
2. Create new row with unique_id = result of 1 query
```

---

I tried

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 9) AS random_number 
FROM table 
HAVING random_number NOT IN (SELECT unique_id FROM table) 
LIMIT 1
```

but it generates not unique values..

Note: multiplier = 9 is given just for example, it is easy to reproduce this problem with such multiplier

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to use the `id` column, just as a random permutation:

```
select id
from tables
order by rand()
limit 1
```

(Your example only returns one value.)

To return a repeatable random number for each id, you can do something like:

```
select id,
       (select count(*) from table t2 where rand(t2.id) < rand(t.id)) as randomnumber
from table t
```

What this is doing is producing a stable sort order by seeding the random number generator.  This guarantees uniqueness, although this is not particularly efficient.

A more efficient alternative that uses variables is:

```
SELECT  id, @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS random_number
FROM table CROSS JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
order by rand()
```

Note:  this returns random numbers up to the size of the table, not necessarily from the ids.  This may be a good thing.

Finally, you can get the idea that you were attempting to work with a bit of a trick.  Calculate an md5 hash, then cast the first four characters as an integer and check back in the table:

```
SELECT convert(hex(left(md5(rand()), 4)), unsigned) AS random_number 
FROM table 
HAVING random_number NOT IN (SELECT unique_id FROM table) 
LIMIT 1
```

You need to insert the value back into the table.  And, there is no guarantee that you will actually be able to get a value not in the table, but it should work for up to millions of values.

Comment: If you need more than one id -- or all of them -- just change the limit clause.  The example in your question only returned one id.  Remove the limit and get a unique number for every id (from the set of ids -- this clearly won't work for the 0-8 example).

Comment: why they be unique? 
    select id
    from tables
    order by rand()
    limit 1
will return duplicates soometimes

Comment: @magalter . ..  I got that.  Your example only returns one row because of the limit.  Once you have a stable sort order (as in the revised example) you'll get unique results.  If you have a lot of data, though, I would use a temporary table.

Comment: I will try to explain my goal.
I need 1 random unique id for newly added record. id field is autoincrement, so it is not random. unique_id is needed to be random.
So before adding new row I need to execute sql query and get 1 random and unique number to insert it as unique_id table.
So algorythm is:
1. Get 1 unique random record for new row
2. Create new row with this record

Comment: I changed my question a little and added alghorytm steps to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the availability to use an MD5 hash as a unique_ID, go for MD5(NOW()). This will almost certainly generate a unique ID every time.

Reference: [MySQL Forums](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,425424,425491#msg-425491)

Comment: unique_id is integer field. I need to be 100% sure that unique_id will be unique.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the multiplier of your `RAND()` function? In  a relative sense, as this pool shrinks, the more liklely an existing identifier will be encountered. Are there any bounds on the size of the unique_id field?

Comment: unique_id is integer(10) unsigned
I added this to the question.
Yes, no problems to increase multiplier, but result numbers will not be unique nevertheless, they can be duplicated sometime :) I need really unique value and I have no room for error.

Comment: multiplier = 9 is given just for example, it is easy to reproducr this problem with such multiplier

Comment: to guarantee uniqueness you may have to complicate things. Adding an IF test in there to check against all existing identifiers would be required.

Comment: So I need a good query that can do such thing and I'm asking for it :) My be with IF condition..